# ElasticSearch: sort in specific order

Tags: elasticsearch

i have an indexed string field in my docs with letters a-z as possible values.
Is it possible to sort the query result in specific(given) order?
Something like:

```
{
    "sort" : [
        { "letters" : {"order" : ["k", "g", "a"...]}}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think instead of sorting you can use function score

```
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {},
        "functions": [
           {
                "field_value_factor": 
                {
                    "field": "rank",
                    "factor": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "filter": {"term": {"letters": "k"}},
                "weight": 50
            },
            {
                "filter": {"term": {"letters": "g"}},
                "weight": 40
            },
            {
                "filter": {"term": {"letters": "a"}},
                "weight": 30
            }
        ],
        "score_mode": "sum",
        "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I will test it. But unfortunately my question was incomplete, I need to sort on 2 fields: first on letters and then on integer field(ranking) on same letters. How to do it with function score?

Comment: Yes it can also work with function score, because function score do the sum on the weight you put. In fact post all your need, I will modify my query if you want

Comment: I need the following: if the letters are equal, order by ranking. in mysql: ORDER BY FIELD(letters, 'k', 'g', 'a'), ranking

Comment: I modify my query please check

Comment: @StefanWeiss is that resolve your problem? if yes could you accept the answer please ?

Comment: it doesn't work as expected. More "weight" results in less score. i have played with boost mode and score mode, but the letters in results still can be mixed

Comment: No the weight should be the bigger the better . I think the problem could be your rank column is bigger than weight this way it will take the rank first. Could you give a rank range ex. 100 level or 10000 level then adjust your weight of letters much bigger than this values. Ex. If rank are all in 100 level you may want to put your weight to 10000 level then when it will do the sum the letter weight will play more important role. Also if you can provide some sample data I can do query base on what you have. Also change the factor to 1.

Comment: So:) My rank is in range 1 to 1000, so i gave "weight" 50000 to 100000 to letters. It Works! Thx!

Comment: Is there a way of implementing this using the java api?